# How to prevent auto closing of soft input panel in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, soft-keyboard

I am facing an unexpected behavior of Keyboard showing and hiding in UWP app working on tablet with windows 10.

After carefully testing again and again i noticed that this issue comes when you have focus on input box and keyboard is opened for it. Now focusing next input needs layout adjustment so that it should not be hidden by keyboard. When you try to focus next element, by default previously opened keyboard hides and now i'm not able to open keyboard un till this new input box lose focus and manually gain focus again.

So for controlling this issue i want to prevent automatic hide and show of keyboard every time i switch focus to new textbox. It should open keyboard once the page load (already found solution using InputPane) and hiding should only be by clicking cancel (x) button.

Please check this video for clearly understanding the issue. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1c876uwytywio1t/Soft%20Keyboard%20Issue.mp4?dl=0

Please vote this suggestion if anyone else is also facing this issue.
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/34170142-inputpane-does-not-open-when-focus-is-shifted-to-n

Comment: Have you tried this in Windows10  1803 Spring Creators Update?

Comment: Yes it's fixed in this new version with some others bugs, links for which are given in my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been partially resolved in windows 10 version 1803 released on 30th  April, 2018. In this version InputPane does not hide and show again and again when focus is shifted from one input element to other.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to put a horizontal-stretched placeholder control (let say, StackPanel) at the bottom of your page, then let it the same size the on-screen keyboard does. That could prevent uncontrolled auto-hide trigger being fired (at least I did that trick on UWP mobile app):

```
// on the window initialization, remember the input pane
this._inputPane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView()
// then, subscribe to the events
_inputPane.Showing = (sender, args) =>
{
    args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = true; // skip default vertical-shift behavior
    this._placeholderPane.Height = args.OccludedRect.Height;
}

_inputPane.Hiding = (sender, args) =>
{
    this._placeholderPane.Height = 0;
}
```

Hope it helps on the Win10 desktop same way as it was on mobile one.

P.S. Yes, initially the placeholder pane is zero-height and collapsed.

Comment: No extra work is required now as it was a bug in previous version of windows which create unexpected behavior when an event is triggered before waiting for closing of previous event. Like when open 2nd ContentDialog suddenly after you close 1st one, then the 2nd one will not wait for proper close of previous one and app will crash. Same was the case with keyboard in which layout update event and hide then show InputPane events mix together. All these issue are fixed in version 1803.

Comment: @ZubairRana, yep, I totally understand that. Just in case you need a workaround to support previous builds too.